# After installing CUDA on ubuntu 14.04 and restarting, got message about failure to install nvidia-340

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I installed CUDA 6.5 on ubuntu 14.04, and after rebooting got a message saying the  installation of nvidia-340 failed. I didn't install a driver along with CUDA (yet) although some installation instructions implied it may well be necessary. Everything display still works as usual after the restart and error message.

Why would this error message show, and would I really need to install a driver along with installing that version of CUDA?

The [FAQ](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) says an option will be displayed to replace my display driver along with the CUDA installation, which I don't recall happening (well, admittedly it was late at night...). So I'm a bit puzzled about all this driver integration.

Conversely, how should I determine if CUDA is good to go and everything is already just in place, in the most straightforward way?

Comment: I would try to de-install all installed nvidia-attempts (and to de-install the attempt with CUDA-driver) - then restart your machine (with VESA) - then only install the CUDA-driver (as suiting to your processor/mainboard/graphics-chip and -card) - it could look similiar like the steps, which are desribed here, where nvidia-trick is solved with optimus-cards (user:105993 [nvidia-optimus]) -

Comment: I am a quite clueless about VESA and what you mean by de-installing  nvidia-attempts...

Comment: What is nvidia-340 anyway? is that the driver coming along with CUDA 6.5? is it a driver that the OS uses to render the desktop display, or is it specific to using CUDA?

Comment: first tell me please the exact type of your graphics card, then tell me please which processor you have (and which bios/mainboard/and if possible whether you have dual-boot with windows or not) -  :-)

Comment: [nvidia-340 seems to be described here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/trusty/main/base/nvidia-340) in a way leaving some doubt as to why it would come along with CUDA. I'll dig all the model info when I come back to it.